# Are these codes immutable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to change state in my component, but I don't know whether this code is immutable. I came up with two ways to solve this problem. Both of these codes work well but don't know if they are immutable. I would be grateful if you could tell me which is better or which is better than these codes.

Trial 1

```
  handleRemove = id => {
    const { dummyData } = this.state;
    delete dummyData[id];

    this.setState({ dummyData });
  };
```

Trial 2

```
  handleRemove = id => {
    const { dummyData } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      dummyData: {
        ...Object.keys(dummyData)
          .filter(key => key !== id)
          .reduce((acc, cur) => {
            return {
              ...acc,
              [cur]: dummyData[cur]
            };
          }, {})
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: `delete dummyData[id];` will surely mutate `dummyData`. Second code doesn't mutate anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trial 1 will mutate `dummyData`, trial 2 will not, but it's overly complicated.

Other alternative are:

- use es6 object destructuring:

  ```
  const { [id]: _, ...dummyData } = this.state.dummyData;
  this.setState({ dummyData });
  ```
- use other utility function like lodash's `_.omit`
- use library that allow you to modify an object freely without mutate it, like [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer).

Comment: For some reason Babel doesn't compile it for me: [link](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBA9gNBCWATOB9A3AKA1CBeCA3gNpIC6AXBCnAHR1QC-mGQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2&version=7.5.5). It says `Property arguments[1] of CallExpression expected node to be of a type ["Expression","SpreadElement","JSXNamespacedName","ArgumentPlaceholder"] but instead got undefined`

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAJgVwLZIJ4BECGVMwLwwDeMAZiCAFwwCMATAMwA0MARpgE5UAsArAGwwAvgChQkWAEs4-GAHIyIWcNHhoRGAG0pAXSoB9ZgDpjiFBmyYA6hKgALEAigBJaYJmm0WHAG4VkEAA2AKaGASAA5gAUHuY41nYOznAAlEA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.5.5&externalPlugins=